# Переход PHP 5.6 на PHP 7

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, нужно соединиться с БД на 5,6 это работало на 7 не работает.

```
defined('firma1') or die('Доступ запрещён!');
$db_host ='host_name';
$db_user ='user_name';
$db_pass ='123456789';
$db_database ='db_name';

$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);

mysql_select_db($db_database,$link) or die("Нет соединения с БД ".mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET names UTF-8");
```

Comment: На всякий случай: 1. `die("Нет соединения с БД ".mysql_error());` не стОит использовать. Такая информация должна записываться в лог и быть доступной только администраторам и разработчикам; 2. `mysql_query("SET names UTF-8");` тоже так себе идея. Есть `mysql_set_charset` и соответсвующий аналог в _mysqli_. За подробностями можно обратиться в соответствующий раздел справки

Answer (score 0):

В PHP 7 удалили данные функции для соединения с БД, теперь это работает на объектно-ориентированный манер:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);
$mysqli->query('<тут SQL запрос>');
```

Подробнее смотрите [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php)

Comment: Вообще-то c `mysqli` и процедурно можно работать.

Answer (score 0):

В PHP7+ убрали несколько расширений, в том числе и *mysql*. Вместо него стОит использовать *mysqli* или *PDO*.

Более полно можно прочитать в разделе [Миграция с PHP 5.6.x на PHP 7.0.x](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.php)